# DNN Search Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am running DNN 9.4.1 and I am using the dnn's search function for my site.

The "See More Results" function on the search bar dropdown does not seem to work.

When i clicked on it, nothing happens and nothing shows up on the browser console either.

Here is a snippet of the js code here:

```
$('.searchSkinObjectPreview_more', $wrap).on('click', function () {
   var $searchButton = $wrap.next();
   if (!$searchButton.length) {
     $searchButton = $wrap.parent().next();
   }
   $searchButton[0].click();
   return false;
});
```

Is there something wrong with the js code here?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Add a console.log to the first line of the event handler to make sure the event is being triggered. If not, check your selectors.  Perhaps log `$wrap` to see if it what you are expecting.

Comment: nothing is showing up in the console though

Comment: i am getting this: "bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3" in the console. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Most definitely

Comment: i am getting logs printed in the console when i click the button, but still nothing is happening.

Comment: We don't have enough info to help further. What is `$wrap`?  Is it what you expect when you log it?  Does logging `$searchButton[0]` give you the result you expect? Is there an actual click event listener attached to `$searchButton[0]`?

Comment: yes, the logs shows up as expected. But it still does not work.

Comment: "Is there something wrong with the js code here?"  - javascript does not work in isolation, to debug further we need the HTML context and more info on the `$wrap` variable. Preferably provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look to the jquery issue first.  See if you can determine there are multiple versions of jQuery being loaded.  If so, try to determine what is loading the out of date one.